I am trying to create aiogram acyncio telegram bot, but I can't call the function in for loop
I have handlers for get message from user and that works, but in for loop I need to stop loop and get new message from user and store it in variable new_answer. Then I need use that variable in if statement
but I don't understand how to do that.
@router.message(F.text == "Let's play!")
async def nice(message: Message, state: FSMContext, new_answer = Playgame.number ):
    await state.set_state(Playgame.number)
    numbers = []
    user_score = 0
    for i in range(1, 101, 1):
        num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
        num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
        result = num1 + num2
        if result not in numbers:
            numbers.insert(0, result)
        else:
            pass
        await message.answer(f'game started at, {i}) {num1}+{num2}=__?', reply_markup=kb.gamekeyboard)
        i += 1
        if int(new_answer) == result:  /*user input should come here/*
            user_score += 1
            await message.reply("Yes right! you score: ", user_score)
        else:
            user_score -=1
            await message.reply("No that is mistake! next question! your score: ", user_score )

@router.message(Playgame.number)  
#that handler try to get number from user input
async def process_number(message: Message, state: FSMContext) -\> None:
    await state.update_data(number=message.text)
    await message.answer(f"Your answer is '{message.text}'")   /*i get Echo msg here/*
    new_answer = await state.get_state() 

That I need use that user input after i += 1 before if statement.

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'State'

Maybe that I am stuck without any solution results, that is my first question so it's to easy to solve.
